# Using kryo TaggedFieldSerializer with fields inherited from parent class

Tags: java, inheritance, serialization, field, kryo

I am trying to use the `TaggedFieldSerializer` from Kryo to be able to serializer/deserialize a POJO I want to send through the wire. I am using `TaggedFieldSerializer` because my POJO keeps evolving and I don't want to break serialization every time it changes. This POJO is actually a child from a parent object and it uses few of the inherited fields.

My problem is that I would not like to change the parent object to use the `Tag` annotation to serialize those fields. Is there anything that Kryo provides to accommodate this scenario? If not, is there any easy workaround I can use?

For more information: [Kryo Compatibility Wiki](https://github.com/EsotericSoftware/kryo#compatibility)